# Last status array with index in Typescript Angular

Tags: typescript, select, arraylist, angular7

I am stuck with this logic.
I have array and function :

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name: any = 'World';

  myArray: any = 
  [
    {
      id: 2001,
      name:"a"
    }, 
    {
      id: 2002,
      name:""
    }, 
    {
      id: 2003,
      name:"b"
    }, 
    {
      id: 2004,
      name:"c"
    }, 
  ];
 
  ngOnInit() {
   this.removeEmptyContent();
  }

  selectFile(event) {
    console.log('event', event);
     
    this.myArray.forEach( (myObject) => {
        console.log('myObject', myObject); 
            if(myObject.length > -1){
                console.log('completed'); 
            } else {
                console.log('in progress'); 
        }
    });   
    console.log('getlast', this.myArray.length > -1);
  }

  removeEmptyContent() {
    this.myArray.forEach( (myObject, index) => {
      if(!myObject.name){
          this.myArray.splice(index, 1);
      }
    });   
  }
}
```

```html
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of myArray">
    <div (click)=selectFile(item)>
      {{item.name}}
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I want that array have different value when selected last item.
When select index 0,1,.. the status in "**progress**" but when select last index i want the status "**complete**". How to do that?

Note: That code above need fix and update

Thank you

Comment: You have names and myArray, which last item are you talking about and NAMES[] stays empty?

Comment: I has update my code, sorry if make you confuse about that. If you can see HTML. The result is list a, b, and c. When click a or b status is "in progress". and the last item status is "complete".

Comment: Is your list ordered or its about the id?

Comment: what best practise to do? This is about list order selected. if select a or b i want show status "in progress" and the last status is "completed"

Comment: You know the order is not necessary kept when retreiving json. If you select c and b would they show as in progress and the last one (a) as completed.

Comment: yes if select a and b show as in progress and the last one (c) as completed. and if select a and c show as in progress and the last one (b) as completed

Comment: So status completed happen if all item has clicked. That mean the last one item status show as completed

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. Its not the cleanest but I think it would work. First you have an array of your selectedItem:

You check if the item selected has already been selected

- If already selected do nothing
- If not, add it to the list
- if the selectedItem list has equal amount of item than myArray, it means that the

Here is the code:

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.removeEmptyContent();
   this.selectedItem = []
  }

  selectFile(event) {
    console.log('event', event);

    if(this.selectedItem.find(item => item.id = event.id)){
        this.selectedItem.push(event)
    }
    if(this.selectedItem.length === this.myArray.length){
        console.log('completed'); 
    } else {
        console.log('in progress');
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but not working. I have try it. Can you see here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hzrvnq. That code i create only completed in last item. But i want like this, if select a and b show as in progress and the last one (c) as completed or if select a and c show as in progress and the last one (b) as completed